# Find X in logarithm

Tags: logarithms

So I have this given problem,

$$ n*lg(n) = x $$

x is given in the problem, for example, 100.
How can I find `n` in this problem?

Comment: What do you denote with $\text{lg}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said in answers,
$$n\log_2(n)=x\implies n=\frac{x \log (2)}{W(x \log (2))}=\frac t {W(t)}$$
using $t=x\log(2)$.

If you cannot use Lambert function, you need a numerical method (Newton as the simplest) and you can generate the starting value $n_0$ which will be updated according to
$$n_{k+1}=\frac{n_k+x \log (2)}{\log (n_k)+1}$$

If $x$ is large, you can use the truncated expansion
$$W(t)=L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}\qquad \text{where}\qquad L_1=\log(t)\qquad L_2=\log(L_1)$$

Trying with $x=2^k$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & n_0 & n \\
 2 & 2.71982 & 2.74537 \\
 3 & 3.72428 & 4.00000 \\
 4 & 5.85865 & 6.12128 \\
 5 & 9.50717 & 9.74309 \\
 6 & 15.7821 & 16.0000 \\
 7 & 26.7297 & 26.9384 \\
 8 & 46.0697 & 46.2749 \\
 9 & 80.6000 & 80.8036 \\
 10 & 142.818 & 143.016
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Using [Lambert's $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), solution is

$$
n = \frac{x}{W(x)}
$$

Otherwise, a numerical solution can be also be found using a root finding algorithm, e.g. [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), in the case $x = 100$ the result is

$$
n \approx 29.54
$$

Answer (score 0):

For large $x$, start from the approximations

$$n\approx\frac x{\log_2x}$$ and $$n\approx2\frac x{\log_2x}.$$

Then refine by dichotomic search.

E.g. for $x=100$, the starting approximations are $15$ and $30$, such that $15\log_215=58.6$ and $30\log_230=147.2$. Then middle value, $22$, yields $22\log_222=98.1$.